# An example of continuous functions on lattices

Tags: lattice-orders

The question is as following:

Design a finite complete lattice $A$, with at least 15 elements. Provide four non-trivial examples of $f:A -> A$ such that $f$ is:

a) non monotone
b) monotone but not continuous
c) a function with no fixpoints
d) continuous.

I am struggling to understand (and then give an example) of continuous/non continuous functions in a lattice. I think that I can deal with parts a and c myself. I am an absolute beginner to lattices, and neither I am studying maths. I checked at some material on the web but I still don't have an idea how you define a continuous function in a lattice.

I would appreciate any answer. So far, I have been just reading for continuous functions on lattices but even finding good references on it is proving to be a challenge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re using the usual definitions, (b) is impossible. A map $f:A\to A$ is continuous if $f(\sup D)=\sup f[D]$ whenever $D$ is a directed subset of $A$. $D\subseteq A$ is directed if each finite subset of $D$ has an upper bound in $D$. Note that when $D$ itself is finite, this just means that it has a maximum element: the finite directed subsets of $A$ are the finite subsets that have a maximum element.

Suppose that $A$ is finite and $f:A\to A$ is monotone, and let $D$ be a directed subset of $A$. Then $D$ has a maximum element $d_0$, so $f(d)\le f(d_0)$ for each $d\in D$, and therefore $f(d_0)=\max f[D]$. That is, $$f(\sup D)=f(\max D)=f(d_0)=\max f[D]=\sup f[D]\;,$$ and $f$ is therefore continuous.

To get a monotone map that isn’t continuous, you’ll need an infinite complete lattice. Here’s a fairly simple example that may help you to see what has to happen. Let $L=\Bbb N\cup\{\infty\}$, with the usual order $\le$ on $\Bbb N$ together with $a\le\infty$ for each $a\in L$. This is a complete lattice. Let

$$f:L\to L:a\mapsto\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }a\in\Bbb N\\
\infty,&\text{if }a=\infty\;;
\end{cases}$$

clearly $f$ is monotone. Next, note that $\Bbb N$ is a directed subset of $L$: if $F$ is any finite subset of $\Bbb N$, then $\max F$ is an upper bound for $F$ in $\Bbb N$. But

$$f(\sup\Bbb N)=f(\infty)=\infty\ne 0=\sup f[\Bbb N]\;,$$

so $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: Thanks a lot!

Anyway, am I right that the following example is a monotonic continuos function:

Every complete lattice has a supremum and an infimum. So let's say we have a lattice with 15 elements. One of them is supremum while one other is infimum. The other 13 elements are in the middle and are linked with both. Our function sends every element to supremum, satisfying the definition of continuos function. In this case, supremum is a fixed point (the only one)

Comment: @Ismail: You're welcome. Yes, any constant function is continuous.

Comment: Thanks again!

It is much clearer now than before.